# Equal area projection of Antarctica ?

Tags: coordinate-system, antarctica, equal-area

I was looking for an equal area projection of Antarctica, but it seems that the Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area (https://epsg.io/3974 , also called 102020 by ESRI) is deprecated because it is not a "true" equal area projection.

Is there any "equal area" projection that I could use as a standard for the South Pole ? If not, what are the possible workarounds ?

Comment: Did you look into EASE Grid 2.0? https://nsidc.org/data/ease/ease_grid2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the chain of references in [Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area  EPSG:3974](https://epsg.io/3974) leads via [NSIDC EASE-Grid South](https://epsg.io/3409) to [WGS 84 / NSIDC EASE-Grid 2.0 South](https://epsg.io/6932) that looks promising.

This points to Brodzik, M. J., B. Billingsley, T. Haran, B. Raup, M. H. Savoie. 2014. [*EASE-Grid 2.0: Incremental but Significant Improvements for Earth-Gridded Data Sets.*](https://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/1/1/32) ISPRS International Journal of Geo-Information 2012, 1, 32-45 & [correction](https://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/3/3/1154) in 2014, 3, 1154-1156.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Turton Do you know more about this projection ? If I just look at the wkt, th only difference is TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0], which should not change anything if I understand well. Would gdal know that it has to take a gridding into account based on the EPSG code ?

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about it more than I found on epsg.io - I tend not to map the polar regions